# JRuby on Rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ssl, jruby, mongrel

I need to host a JRuby on Rails app on Mongrel. The problem is that I need to support mutual authentication. I know that I could just host it behind a Apache with mod_proxy use mod_ssl to pass the cred or part of the cred as a request header to rails. But I want the whole stack to be Java. Is there a Java application server that can do mod_proxy + ssl kind of configuration without me having to install Apache. Also, we need this to be platform independent. IIS or Apache+OpenSSL is actually not a preferred alternative.

Any alternative deployment configurations are also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I'd actually recommend using either [jetty](http://jetty-rails.rubyforge.org/) or [glassfish](http://developers.sun.com/appserver/reference/techart/rails_gf/) for deploying your app. You can run mongrel in JRuby, but it's very [slow](http://blog.headius.com/2007/09/end-is-near-for-mongrel.html) and no longer actively maintained. I definitely wouldn't use it for a production enviroment (in JRuby at least). I find jetty to be more lightweight, both suppport SSL ([Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+configure+SSL), [Glassfish](http://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/using_ssl_in_glassfish)).